# Launching a RemoteApp programmatically without a system call to "mstsc"

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, remoteapp

I've an RDP file that successfully start a RemoteApp.

```
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||application
remoteapplicationname:s:application.exe
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:
authentication level:i:2
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:aaa.bbb.ccc.com
```

I tried to copy its settings into my C# objects:

```
AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting rc = new AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting();
rc.OnConnected += (_1, _2) => { rc.RemoteProgram2.ServerStartProgram("application.exe", "", "%HOMEDRIVE%" + "%HOMEPATH%", true, "", true); };
rc.RemoteProgram2.RemoteProgramMode = true;
rc.RemoteProgram2.RemoteApplicationProgram = "||application";
rc.RemoteProgram2.RemoteApplicationName = "application.exe";
rc.TransportSettings.GatewayUsageMethod = 1;
rc.TransportSettings.GatewayProfileUsageMethod = 1;
rc.TransportSettings.GatewayCredsSource = 0; 
rc.Server = "aaa.bbb.ccc.com";
rc.UserName = "DOMAIN\\user";
rc.AdvancedSettings7.PublicMode = false;
rc.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = "pass";
rc.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel = 2;
rc.DesktopWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
rc.DesktopHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;
rc.AdvancedSettings7.SmartSizing = true;
rc.Connect();
```

I've been searching everywhere but I wasn't able to find any example of how to launch a RemoteApp programmatically.

I've red [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837808/hosting-remoteapp-session-within-winform), but it was not very helpfull. The client (a COM control) is connecting successfully, but it just displays a blue screen and no RemoteApp is launched.

Furthermore, I'm not sure that the right method to launch `rc.RemoteProgram2.ServerStartProgram`, because it takes paths as arguments, while in my RDP file no path is present!

Can anyone help me? I'm using the right objects to do what I want?

The server runs Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: Any news? I need exactly same thing...

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is pragmatically launch a RemoteApp you already have an rdp file for, then just start it as a process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Path_To_Rdp_File.rdp");
```

Comment: This is quite the same that launching mstsc... I'd like to launch the remote app as "an object" of my application.